# prebuilt ffmpeg library for android

Tags: android, stream, ffmpeg, udp, cygwin

Nice being here.
I researched a lot on the topic but now i am stuck.

Currently i try to receive a udp stream within android, i am using the libraries from http://code.google.com/p/javacv/downloads/list, most of the things work fine. However if i try to use "avformat_network_init();" (thanks to this [Receiving RTSP stream using FFMPEG library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715170/receiving-rtsp-stream-using-ffmpeg-library)) i get the following error:

**undefined reference to `avformat_network_init'**

my guess is that the prebuilt library called "libavformat.so" does not contain the specific function, am i right? if so, does anyone know where i can find the appropriate library? I am developing on windows and failed already building it myself with cygwin and currently have not the option to install ubuntu or such.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a wide search through the internet, i gave up on finding a prebuilt library and did it myself (with all the options i need). Self made solutions are often the best choice also if at first thought it doesn't seem to be the better choice, I experienced again, that it is the better one.

What I did was to use the virtual machine (ubuntu) from: http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/wiki/HowToBuild
There you have ffmpeg already downloaded including libx264. Also an instruction is included how to build the whole thing. You can edit the build_ffmpeg.sh and change "features" you want to enable or disable.
In the end it was the cleaner, better and faster solution than to search for one. ;)

good luck anyways!

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Do you have an example project that you are using?

Comment: nothing i could release right now, however what exactly do you need?