# Parse PCM audio data from RTP packet

Tags: c, audio, rtsp, rtp, pcm

I am building a c application for receiving RTSP audio (16bit, Linear PCM). I have completed the RTSP handshakes and  getting RTP audio data from server (TCP transport, UDP is not possible in my case, firewall limitation). For parsing the audio data (PCM) from RTP payload what should i do.
i have tried to remove the RTP header from received packet (First 12 bytes), but the audio i got have continuous jitter. Is there any example codes or an methods for parsing the payload from RTP packet.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you fully respect the [header specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol#Packet_header)?

Decoding audio frames can be tricky, I recommend using [FFMPEG libraries](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Using%20libav*).

Some [good examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715170/receiving-rtsp-stream-using-ffmpeg-library) can be found on Stack Overflow.